# where memcached spends time?

Tags: nosql, memcached, libmemcached

I am running some experiments with memcached on Linux (x86-64). I am generating queries to the memcached server using memslap utility. I notice that memcached spends most of time is spent on system (i.e, OS functions). I was wondering if anybody has some insights about which functionality of OS is used heavily by memcached and thus spends most of its time on it.

Thanks

Arka

Answer (score 0):

Memcached only major OS function, outside of daemon process, is related to the [libevent](http://libevent.org/). I believe memcached & libmemcached is compiled with OS's shared libevent library, and that *time* will be generalized as an OS function.